# Upgrading to ArcGIS 10.3 geodatabase on windows R2 SP2 and Oracle 10g (64 bit) 10.2.0.5?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, oracle-spatial, migration

We have Oracle 10g (64 bit) 10.2.0.5 on Windows Server 2008 Enterprise SP2, and we are planning to migrate our geodatabase from 9.3.1 to 10.3.

As per Esri ["Oracle database requirements for ArcGIS 10.3.x](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/get-started/system-requirements/database-requirements-oracle.htm)" the maximim OS is SP1.

Does anyone know what is limitation/risk/impacts if we keep our OS SP2 not SP1 and migrate our geodatabase?

And what if we migrate our ArcGIS Server/Desktop to 10.3 and kept using geodatabase 9.3.1?

Comment: Databases can only store features that are valid for their version. Since 9.3 for example the Mosaic Dataset has been introduced, as you database precedes 10.1 you cannot create one there but would instead have to create one in a file geodatabase. Your Oracle should work as it currently does and will store simple features as normal... I would think that SP2 should be fine, to be sure contact Esri directly and ask why it is that SP2 isn't listed... it could be that it works and is just not tested, thereby not guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 1):

You have misinterpreted the meaning of the supported environment pages.  Esri *never* specifies a "maximum OS".  All it does is report **tested and certified** configurations.  Older configurations are unsupported, and for newer ones, the [Supported Environment Policy](http://support.esri.com/en/content/supportedenvironmentpolicy) states:

> That environment is supported if it meets or exceeds the base build environment and that environment is known to not fail.

Your risk is in using an ancient operating system, with an ancient Oracle install, with ancient Java components, quite likely on ancient hardware.  Each of these things is individually much more hazardous to your infrastructure than using SP2 over SP1 on an OS which already requires additional payment for security patch updates.

You cannot leave your geodatabase at 9.3.1, because [9.3.1 geodatabases are not supported with ArcGIS 10.3 ("connect only to upgrade")](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/client-geodatabase-compatibility.htm).

ArcGIS 10.3 already [requires an Oracle 11g or 12c client to connect to 10gR2 databases](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/get-started/system-requirements/database-requirements-oracle.htm); you should start preparing for the day when Oracle 10gR2 is not supported at all.